# How to modify markup in ASP.NET without using Response Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

Since ASP.NET response filtering and post-cache substitution are not compatible, I need an alternative way of filtering output. Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2014472

Is there any way to change the markup without using response filter?

Comment: Great question. One might reasonably expect MS to have a plan 'B' on offer since this is clearly a breaking change. Sadly, I've been unable to find a good one to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an official "answer" from MS Dev Support on this issue.

**Question:**
What is the alternative to response filtering in ASP.NET for modifying HTML rendered by another process when:
1.  The other process cannot be modified
2.  Post-cache substitution must be supported

**Answer:**
"Yes, you question is clear as blue sky and this is officially claimed to be not support. As Post-cache substitution would combine certain substitution chunks to the response bytes while response filtering expects to filter the raw bytes of the response(not modified). So the previously combined substitution chunks cannot be preserved anymore.

There is not an alternative from Microsoft so far."